# Create a macro which will remove duplicated data and move data from cells to appear in a single row

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-2010

I am trying to write a macro which will remove some duplicated ID from a singl column so that it only appears once in the column and put the data from the Item cell into the row of that item.

example of what my excel spreadsheet looks like so far: -

```
 A   B        c
1    ID       Name          Item
2   555      Joe Bloggs     Orange
3   555      Joe Bloggs     Blue
4   454      Gale Force     Orange
5   333      Justin Store   Green
6   333      Justin Store   Purple
7   333      Justin Store   Blue
8   525      Graham Wood    Pruple
```

It goes on randonly like that some so of the ID appear more then 4 times but each with different items.  What I want is it to appear like this: -

```
A    B         C            D         E          F         G
1   ID       Name          Item      Item       Item       Item
2   555      Joe Bloggs    Orange    Blue
3   454      Gale Force    Orange  
4   333      Justin Store  Green    Purple      Blue
5   525      Graham Wood   Pruple
```

Is it possible to write a macro that will do this?

Appologies for the names etc in the example, I can not actually attach a copy of the document or enter the same data so I have made the info up but the principle is the same.

Thanks

Comment: As the VBA engine satisfies the criteria of being a General Turing machine, the answers is "Yes, it its possible." If you would like assistance in writing such a macro, please post an attempt first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following Macro.  It works for your example with a header row in Row 1 and real data starting in A2:

```
Sub flatten()
    Dim ro As Integer
    Dim oRow As Integer
    Dim rng As Range

    For ro = 1 To Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(ro, 1))
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, Cells(ro, 1)) > 1 Then
            oRow = rng.Find(Cells(ro, 1), MatchCase:=True).Row
            Cells(oRow, Cells(oRow, 1).End(xlToRight).Column + 1) = Cells(ro, 3)
            Rows(ro).Delete
            ro = ro - 1
        End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Glad I can help.  Do you mind marking the answer as correct so other's know your issue is resolved?

Answer (score 0):

This Sub-procedure works for me:

```
Sub MakeUniqueAndTranspose()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    RowCount = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = RowCount To 2 Step -1
       With Range("C" & i)
           If .Value <> .Offset(-1).Value Then Rows(i).Insert
       End With
    Next i
    For Each Area In Columns("D").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Areas
       Area(1).Offset(, 1).Resize(, Area.Rows.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(Area)
    Next Area
    'delete the created empty columns between every value
    Columns("C").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    'delete original column which is now obsolete
    Columns("D").Delete
    'remove the duplicates which are now empty
    Columns("D:D").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, but unfortunatley this did not work, I got a run time error when I tried to use this code, it also left blank rows where to information had been deleted.  The code above yours works fine, but thank you for your help, much appreciated.